# Error while creating JMS configuration in wso2esb

Tags: jms, wso2, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2esb4.7.0 and wso2mb-2.2.0. I wish to create jms proxy service using wso2mb. For this i have configured the wso2mb as well as wso2esb like :

Wso2esb configuration :
(changes in jndi.properties)

```
# register some connection factories
# connectionfactory.[jndiname] = [ConnectionURL]
 connectionfactory.QueueConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5673'
 connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5673'


# register some queues in JNDI using the form
# queue.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
queue.MyQueue = MyQueue
```

changes in axis2.xml :

uncomment following code :

```
 <transportSender name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender"/>

 <transportReceiver name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
        <parameter name="myTopicConnectionFactory" locked="false">
           <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">TopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">topic</parameter>
        </parameter>

        <parameter name="myQueueConnectionFactory" locked="false">
            <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
           <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
        </parameter>

        <parameter name="default" locked="false">
            <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">ConnectionFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
        </parameter>
    </transportReceiver>
```

also copied `andes-client-*.jar` and `geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-*.jar` from $MB_HOME/client-lib to $ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib

re-started servers.Till it's working fine.

Now wish to create a service with jms port. it is creating a service but immediately it goes to faulty service and esb logs it showing error like :

```
 ERROR - JMSListener Unexpected error when configuring service SampleJMS for the JMS transport. It will be disabled for this transport and marked as faulty.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener.getConnectionFactory(JMSListener.java:132)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSEndpoint.loadConfiguration(JMSEndpoint.java:193)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListenerEx.startListeningForService(AbstractTransportListenerEx.java:153)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.internalStartListeningForService(AbstractTransportListener.java:213)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener$2.serviceAdded(AbstractTransportListener.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.tracker.AxisServiceTracker.serviceAdded(AxisServiceTracker.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.tracker.AxisServiceTracker.start(AxisServiceTracker.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.start(AbstractTransportListener.java:178)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListenerEx.start(AbstractTransportListenerEx.java:83)
```

also while restarting it showing error like :

ERROR - BaseUtils JNDI lookup of name ConnectionFactory returned a org.wso2.andes.client.AMQQueue while a interface javax.jms.ConnectionFactory was expected
[2015-01-20 10:22:27,709] ERROR - ListenerManager Couldn't initialize the jmstransport listener
org.apache.axis2.transport.base.BaseTransportException: JNDI lookup of name ConnectionFactory returned a org.wso2.andes.client.AMQQueue while a interface javax.jms.ConnectionFactory was expected

My proxy configuration is :

```
  <target> 
      <inSequence> 
         <property name="Action" 
                   value="urn:placeOrder" 
                   scope="default" 
                   type="STRING"/> 
         <log level="full"/> 
         <send> 
            <endpoint> 
               <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/> 
            </endpoint> 
         </send> 
      </inSequence> 
      <outSequence> 
         <drop/> 
      </outSequence>
```

Why so? is their any problem with jms configuration? Please guide me.

Comment: Can you include the XML of the failing proxy in your question too?

Answer (score 1):

in jndi.properties, you've defined :

- **QueueConnectionFactory**
- **TopicConnectionFactory**

and in axis.xml, you use :

- **QueueConnectionFactory**
- **TopicConnectionFactory**
- AND, in the default part, a "**ConnectionFactory**"

I don't use WSO2MB by I wonder if this would not be your problem

Comment: Thanks Jean-Michel..This is basic configuration.I did it previously