# WSO2 MB JSP Exception while including queue_details.jsp

Tags: wso2, wso2-message-broker

I just downloaded, installed, and started WSO2 Message Broker V2.2.0. When I attempt to "Browse Queues" via the management console I get the following error

"Error during rendering javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: IO Error executing tag: JSPException while including path '/queues/queue_details.jsp'. ServletException while including page"

Has anyone seen this error or have any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: Have you tried to google the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while creating jms proxy in wso2esb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060016/error-while-creating-jms-proxy-in-wso2esb)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was incorrectly using JDK/JRE 8, which is not supported for WSO2 MB V2.2.0. When I installed JDK 7 and updated JAVA_HOME to point to it the message broker management console worked just fine and I could list the queues. Next time I need to do a better job reading the pre-requisite product installs ;-)